# Linear affine random dynamical systems - positive lyapunov exponents?

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, dynamical-systems

Consider the affine random dynamical system
$$
X_n = \mathbf A_n X_{n-1} + R_n, 
$$
where $\mathbf A_n\in\mathbb C^{d\times d}$ and $R_n\in\mathbb C^{d}$ with $R_n$ almost surely not equal to the zero vector. Is it possible to show that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log||X_n|| \geq 0?$$